# When I specify user in get_context_data my context object becomes empty

Tags: python, html, django

On my photo album website users should see only images they uploaded but when I specify user in `get_context_data` my context object becomes empty:

```
#views.py
class PhotoList(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Photo
    template_name = 'main/gallery.html'
    context_object_name = 'photos'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)

        category = self.request.GET.get('category')

        if category == None:
            context['photos'] = Photo.objects.all()
        else:
            context['photos'] =Photo.objects.filter(category__name=category)

        context['photos'] = context['photos'].filter(user=self.request.user)
        context['categories'] = Categories.objects.all()

        return context

    #models.py
class Categories(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=70, null=False, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
         return self.name


class Photo(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Categories,       on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    image = models.ImageField(null=False, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
         return self.description
```

Template:

```
<img  src="{{photo.image.url}}" class="image-thumbnail" >
<div class="card-body">
<h5 class="card-title">Category:{{photo.category}}</h5>
<p class="card-text">{{photo.description}}</p>
```

Comment: The code looks correct. Are you logged in as a user which owns some photos? Put some debugging statements in get_context_data to check what filters you are applying and how many results three are. I suspect zero.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show an image of the user that created a Photo objects and link them to a Categories objects in the Photo model, you have to add a `user` field to the Categories model.

```
Class Categories(models.Model):
    #added field
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=70, null=False, blank=False)
```

To show an image to the user that create them, you can use a function base view:

```
def get_user_photo(request, photo_id):
    category = get_object_or_404(Categories, pk=photo_id)
    photos = Photo.objects.filter(category_id=category.pk)
    context = {
        'photos': photos
        }
    return render (request, 'main/gallery.html', context)
```

And now User can access the images that he/she created:

```
 {% for photo in photos %}
    <img  src="{{photo.image.url}}" class="image-thumbnail" >
    <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Category:{{photo.category}}</h5>
    <p class="card-text">{{photo.description}}</p>
 {% endfor %}
```

Or you can use `user=request.user` like that:

```
def get_user_photo(request):
    photos = Photo.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    context = {
        'photos': photos
        }
    return render (request, 'main/gallery.html', context)
```

You can again access them using `for loop` in the template:

```
{% for photo in photos %}
    <img  src="{{photo.image.url}}" class="image-thumbnail" >
    <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Category:{{photo.category}}</h5>
    <p class="card-text">{{photo.description}}</p>
 {% endfor %}
```

If you want a user to select a categories that you wanted to save an image to in the Photo form, then you can do this:

```
class PhotoAdd(CreateView):
    model = Photo
    form_class = Photo form
    template_name = 'main/create_photo.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('Homepage')

    def get_form(self, form_class=None):
        form = super().get_form(form_class)
        form.fields['category'].queryset = Categories.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
        return form

        def form_valid(self, form):
            form.instance.user = self.request.user
            return super(PhotoAdd, self).form_valid(form)
```